# For 3D reconstruction, is it better to align stereo cameras horizontally vs. vertically?

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

Typically 3D reconstruction is done by aligning 2 cameras horizontally. What are the downsides, if any, of aligning cameras vertically?

Comment: Hmm... No, I don't think that alignment is either vertical or horizontal, it depends. Could you please define what you mean mathematically (the terms you employ are a bit vague for me)? Not necessarily equations, just tell us what operations you carry (pose estimation? matching? What cost function(s) are you using? There are many ways of aligning cameras). Also, could you maybe point us to the references/papers you are using? Thanks!

Comment: In general, cameras are not aligned, and need to be calibrated. Some systems, such as the kinekt, removed the need of calibration by making the cameras fixed. However, in general, there is no aligment, just 2 cameras looking at the same thing